# How to read a config file without keys in python

Tags: python, configuration-files

So i have created a config file & need to read data from it.

The config file looks like:-

```
[Sport]

Cricket

Soccer

Tennis
```

where Sport is the section name & rest are the keys.

I am able to read the file without values by using allow_no_value=True option.

My problem is I need to print 1st record in Sport section & store it in a variable.

My code till now:-

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)

config.read('sport.ini')                    
val1 = config.get('Sport')                  
print val1
```

It shows me an error as:-

```
val1 = config.get('Sport')                  
TypeError: get() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Kindly let me know how to get the 1st record from config file & store it in a variable.

Comment: in the future to add code formatting, use 4 spaces in front of code lines.

Comment: yeah but... does it NEED to be formatted like that? Are you given the config file or can you change it? If so, use [YAML](http://yaml.org/) or something.

Comment: I am using stackoverflow  for the first time. Didn't know how to do. Thanks for your advice. Will follow it next time onwards :)

Comment: Do you by any chance work for Cloudnet or have them as a hosting provider? Is it their infamous .yaml files which really are invalid .config, .conf or .cnf files? :D

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.ConfigParser.items):

```
>>> results = config.items('Sport')
>>> results[0]
('cricket', None)
```

Comment: I only want cricket to be stored in a variable.
As per your solution I am getting cricket & none both in the variable.

Comment: I found out a way, though you were pointing me towards the solution. But it was not an exact solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the key also

```
>>>print(config.get('Sport', 'Cricket'))
None
```

OR to view all key value pairs

```
>>>config.items('S')
[('cricket', None), ('soccer', None), ('tennis', None)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and easy approach. m has the keys and q has the respective values.

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('file.ini')
config['section_name']
for m in config['postgresql']:
    q=config['postgresql'][m]
    print(m,q)
```